# Is $\overline{A^C} = \overline{A}^C$?

Tags: general-topology

Let $A$ be a subset of $X$.

Is $\overline{A^C} = \overline{A}^C$?

where $\overline{A}$ is closure of $A$, and $A^C = X-A$

If not, can you give me some counter-examples?

Comment: It is false, consider $(0,1)\subseteq \Bbb{R}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, it is not true. For instance, in $\mathbb R$ we have$$\overline{\mathbb Q^\complement}=\mathbb R\text{ and }\overline{\mathbb Q}^\complement=\emptyset.$$

Comment: That's a really slick example :)

Answer (score 1):

No, see the answer of José.

What we do have is: $$\overline{A^{\complement}}=\left(A^o\right)^{\complement}$$ where $A^o$ denotes the interior of $A$.